# STM32G431 SPI DR Problem

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm using STM32G431 for practicing SPI protocol knowledge, but face some problems like below.

​I use the HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT API to send (0x5A,0xA5) data out, but I measure the wrong data with an oscilloscope.

In SPI_TxISR_8BIT show how data move to Data Register, but see the watch window DR gets the wrong data.

[image]

Why did that happen?

I have checked hardware settings & all registers to find any similar problem, but that did not help.

```
/**************************************************************/ 

void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */

  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;

  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**************************************************************/ 


void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* spiHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(spiHandle->Instance==SPI1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 0 */
    /* SPI1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**SPI1 GPIO Configuration
    PA4     ------> SPI1_NSS
    PA5     ------> SPI1_SCK
    PB4     ------> SPI1_MISO
    PB5     ------> SPI1_MOSI
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* SPI1 DMA Init */
    /* SPI1_TX Init */
    hdma_spi1_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel1;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_SPI1_TX;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi1_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(spiHandle,hdmatx,hdma_spi1_tx);

    /* SPI1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 1 */
    NSS_SET(0);
  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

/**************************************************************/
```

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: Refer to the [Fine Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0440-stm32g4-series-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), section 39.9.4 on page 1787. There it tells you that reading the DR accesses the Receive FIFO - so you can't look at the DR and expect to see what you just wrote there, because what you write goes to the Transmit FIFO.

Comment: Hi @LongPham,

Thanks for reply!

I have updated code, please have a look.

Hans

Comment: Hi @brhans,

Thanks for reply!

DR cannot be read, this is right.
But in the code logically, the data move to DR should be the same as TxBuffer

Comment: And yet in your question you write "but see the watch window DR gets the wrong data" and you show us a screen capture highlighting the DR - which to me implies that you're expecting to see what you're written into the DR, and as we see in the manual this is not the case. The only place you'll see data you put into the DR is coming out on the SPI MOSI pin. So what do you actually see there?

Comment: Hi @brhans,

In line 3842,can find out 【 *(__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->DR = (*hspi->pTxBuffPtr);】
Is that mean TxBuffPtr move to DR?
Cause I have measured the MOSI with oscilloscope, then back to figure out what happened in my code with debugger.
And I measure that is the same as DR data.
Do you have any ideal can help to solve this?
Really thanks!

Comment: @HANSCHEN I meant you should post the user code, what you have posted is STM32CubeMX generated code. If the configuration was fine, there might be problems with the usage of these HAL functions.